# Kivy выдает ошибку при запуске ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

Эта ошибка выдается при запуске программы, какие могут способы ее решения ?

Comment: установить kivy?

Comment: Вы уверены что модуль установлен? Проверьте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

`win + R`

В поле ввода пишите `cmd` -> Нажимаете Enter

В появившейся командной строке пишите:
`pip3 install kivy`

Радуетесь простоте Путхона

---

Всем добра-бобра